# Efficient data structure to find intersection of two lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I have two very large `List<List<int>>` A and B. I need to find intersection in between each element of those lists.

```
A[0] = { 1, 2, 3};
B[0] = {2, 3, 4};

Intersection = { 2, 3 };
```

My implementation:

```
List<int> intersection = A[0].Intersection(B[0]).ToList();
```

This solution takes very long time to execute. I am wondering if there are any better way to do this and any more efficient data structure I can use to perform it in better time.

Thanks!

Comment: good question thang - that would make things much easier

Comment: Only one set needs to be sorted to employ a binary search. Pick one. 

The OP's question is exactly analogous to a foreign key lookup in a relational database.

Not specified is whether A or B are allowed to have duplicate values, and what should happen if they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a Hashset for this, in C# [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). Lookups in hashsets are O(1) (if decent hashing function and using an array underneath) as opposed to O(n) for lists.

Using Linq in C# you basically get this "built-in": [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) will use a hashset internally to compute the intersection in O(n) instead of O(n^2) if using two lists.

```
var intersection = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. What about `.ToList()` is it produces additional O(N) complexity, how can I avoid it?

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but it's worth remembering that something that is O(1) can still be slower than something that is O(n).

These characteristics don't specify the time to complete a search, they specify how that time changes as the set size increases. A hash computation that is expensive can under-perform O(n) simple compares. 

This is one of the almost universally overlooked reasons that hash tables almost never perform up to peoples' expectations relative to binary searches.

Answer (score 1):

Code sample using [HashSet(T).IntersectWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx):

```
HashSet<string> lst1 = new HashSet<string> 

     { "id1", "id2", "id3" };

HashSet<string> lst2 = new HashSet<string> 

     { "id2", "id3", "id4" };

// what happens is that, lst1 will be modified by only leaving the intersect items
lst1.IntersectWith(lst2);
```

PS: I used the sample for String, but you can utilize your own integer values.